# Chart JS Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, charts

I am using chartjs for the first time .

I have tried to test a simple bar chart from chartjs module.But i`m not able to

view any chart in my browser .Please let me know if i`m making any mistake.

Below i have added the HTML source that i`m using,please go through it .
Thank You

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  
       <script>
 var Chart = require('chart.js');
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
         labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
         datasets: [{
             label: '# of Votes',
             data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
             backgroundColor: [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
             ],
             borderColor: [
                 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
             ],
             borderWidth: 1
         }]
     },
     options: {
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 ticks: {
                     beginAtZero:true
                 }
             }]
         }
     }
 });
 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try to execute your code in onload or document.ready , insteand of doing directly ?

Comment: You need to include require js as well

Comment: how can i do that ...?

Comment: where will i get require.js

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the `script` before `body` so `document.getElementById("myChart");` resulting into `undefined`. Move the `script` below `body` and it will work fine.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

**P.S** No need to include `var Chart = require('chart.js');` in the script

Comment: Glad I helped. Please accept the answer for future reference to others :)

Comment: How can i set Max size in these charts

Comment: @RD063 max size as in size of chart??

Comment: No its iteams, means vertical bar size like in this case its 20 how can i use quantities in 1000 or more

Comment: @RD063 it will increase automatically depending on the dataset of y axis

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body tag and see if it's working

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are you working on plain html, css or is this a framework? Why are you using require js?

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the element not being present in the HTML when Chart.js was trying to attach the chart on it and no need require('chart.js').

Try adding the script files and code after the canvas element.